# Google -Bigquery Error " Not found: Dataset prime-poc:churn was not found in location US"

Tags: google-bigquery

While predicting the Customer churn for Kaggle dataset using Google's Big query.  I am hitting "Not found: Dataset prime-poc:churn was not found in location US". 
This is depie the fact that churn_table is loaded in US location. Please let me know how to overcome this issue. My verification efforts are stalled due to this issue. Any quick help will  be greatly appreciate.

Big query command used :

FROM
      `ccpchurndataset.Churn_table`

NOTE :  both ccpchurndataset and Churn_table are in US location only.

Comment: try providing full qualified path like `FROM \`project.dataset.table\``

Answer (score 1):

Specify fully qualified name ProjectId.DatasetId.TableId enclosed in () tick sign.